# Should theory be the appropriate term?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, models

Should [theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory) be the appropriate term? I mean, for example, because of the quantum field theory we have been able to find the subatomic particles that it theorized and make the Standard Model. Why then is is labeled as a theory? Also wave-particle duality is widely accepted fact yet labeled as a theory. What is up with that, why call it a theory. Maybe because it promotes the fact of idealism?

Comment: It's called a theory because we don't know if it's correct. Evolution is a theory. Gravity is a theory. Wave-particle duality is part of a theory. They just happen to make predictions that coincide reasonably well with the available observational data on how the world operates, so they're considered well-grounded theories. But they're still theories.

Comment: Despite what it said in your grade-school textbook there is not and never has been a precise and rigid definition of any of the words "theory", "law", "principle", in the context of science.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6271) and/or [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77465).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laws and theories](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6271/)

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_theory:

"Scientific theories are testable and make falsifiable predictions. They describe the causal elements responsible for a particular natural phenomenon, and are used to explain and predict aspects of the physical universe or specific areas of inquiry[...]. Scientists use theories as a foundation to gain further scientific knowledge, as well as to accomplish goals such as inventing technology or curing disease. Scientific theories are the most reliable, rigorous, and comprehensive form of scientific knowledge. **This is significantly different from the common usage of the word "theory", which implies that something is a guess** "

Comment: Interchanging theory and scientific theory is a common misconstruction (intendet or not) from creationist, when stating "evolution is just a theory"

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the world "theory" can also be used in the sense of "mathematical theory", which is just a bunch of deductions from axioms, with no particular notion of testability implied.

Comment: Like hyberbolic space for example? That's mathematics, not natural science. Please give an example. Even Schrödingers Equation, which seems to be purely axiomic is a tranferred analogy from optics Eikonal equation.

Comment: I'm not criticising, just adding to your point. An example from mathematics is "set theory": that theory isn't the kind that can be falsified. Arguably, the "theory" in "quantum field theory" refers to it being a mathematical theory in this sense, rather than a scientific theory. (But as dmckee says, the terminology is very subjective anyway.)

Comment: I agree with Nathaniel in that mathematics is a consistent "theory" , euclidean geometry for example. It has axioms, theorems provable and ends with QED. Physics "theories" must have a successful mathematical theory with a QED at the end BUT also have postulates on top of the axioms  that tie the mathematics with measurable quantities predicted by the setup. If the predictions fail to fit reality, then the postulates are falsified, i.e. the physical theory is falsified. example : the square of the wavefunction is the probability of measuring a value.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure for the questioner to separate those terms clearly

Answer (score 0):

Terminology doesn't matter much as long as people understand the ideas involved. You should call and idea whatever you want to call it as long as you are clear about the substance of your ideas.

Some commentators have stated that the Standard Model or other scientific results are well-grounded. So far, these ideas have not been refuted. If somebody invented a competing theory, then that theory would have to solve the same problems the current theory solves. Since the current theory solves a lot of problems that is difficult. However, any given theory is either right or wrong and no number of experimental results that agree with a theory prove it is true or that it is probably true or anything like that.

See "Realism and the Aim of Science" by Karl Popper, especially the first chapter, and on the definition issue see "Conjectures and Refutations" by Popper Chapter 3, Section 3.