# When will Einstein's theories become laws?

Tags: general-relativity, relativity, bose-einstein-condensate, category-theory

Einstein theories , specifically relativity, have been fascinating us for around 100 years yet with all the real and actual evidence of its validity we still consider it a "theory".....
How much more evidence do we need to make Einstein's theories into (or any theory really) confirmed facts and laws?

I'm new to this site and feel like my question might be misplaced. I'm sorry if it is and please correct me :)

Thx in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if something is a primitive concept, a law, a definition or a theorem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77465/how-to-know-if-something-is-a-primitive-concept-a-law-a-definition-or-a-theore)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/laws-and-theories and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103813/should-theory-be-the-appropriate-term and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/can-a-scientific-theory-ever-be-absolutely-proven .

Comment: Since I'm voting to close, I'll leave this as just a remark rather than an answer. This question stems from a mistaken understanding of the word *theory*. The word *theory* in lay terms has somehow devolved to meaning an idea pulled out of an orifice. That is not what the term means in science. A scientific theory is the epitome of science. Scientific laws? They're just equations that don't even have to be universal. (E.g., Ohm's law.)

Comment: law is a XIXe century concept. Now there are facts, theories and models or else facts, models and theories

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out the faults in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question [Laws and theories](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/laws-and-theories) and the answers to it. The terms *law* and *theory* are somewhat vaguely defined so your question doesn't make sense.

Relativity, both special and general, is well enough tested that physicists regard it as an excellent working description of the universe. However it can only be an effective theory since it does not take into account quantum effects. We expect that its predictions will be wrong in regimes where quantum gravity becomes important.